# A Winter's Tale Help, 'He something seemed...'

Tags: shakespeare

There is a children's copy of A Winter's Tale at work with a line I didn't understand (browsing whilst waiting for the microwave!).  It says 'He something seemed unsettled' (Hermione talking about Leontes).

I haven't read any Shakespeare (apart from Romeo and Juliet at school) so I'm sure there's much more I wouldn't get but this keeps bugging me!

Thanks,

Gary

Comment: Usage changes over time, but it's not that different to modern *He seemed **somewhat** unsettled*. And colloquially we still say *It hurts **something** awful*.

Answer (score 1):

This is from Act 1, scene 2 in *The Winter's Tale* (I.2.147). In this context, "something" means "somewhat" or "a little".

In The Penguin Shakespeare edition of the play, Ernest Schanzer glossed "something" as "somewhat". In The Oxford Shakespeare (not the single-volume edition but the series with individual volumes per play), Stephen Orgel also glossed "something" as "somewhat". In The Arden Shakespeare (second series) J. H. P. Pafford did not provide a footnote for "something".

I also consulted the edition hosted on [Shakespeare's Words](http://shakespeareswords.com/Plays.aspx?Ac=1&SC=2&IdPlay=35#240843), which glosses the word as "a little, to some extent".

Comment: never heard "gloss" used in that context.  So, learned something unexpected from this answer.

Comment: @am21 "Gloss" as a verb is quite common in annotated editions of Shakeseare's plays.